# Strongly time-varying behaviour of Ethernet

Tags: ethernet

Recently, I've connected two devices using a 20 meter long Ethernet cable. This solved a huge problem with my Wi-Fi (as I've reduced the distance from 20+ to 4 meters and also avoided some obstacles to the signal), but another problem emerged. My connection to the Internet looks like

```
computer --(Wi-Fi)-- device1 --(ethernet)-- device2 ....
```

My connection to device1 works always well (<1% packets lost), but my connection to device2 makes strange things: sometimes it works well too, sometimes 50% packets get lost, sometimes nearly all of them. The behavior changes very rapidly, two measurements in row may give totally different results, as if there were some strong jamming. The result from running

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do ping -fq 10.0.7.1 100 1000; done
```

in Cygwin follows:

```
1521 packets transmitted, 1000 packets received, 34.3% packet loss
4468 packets transmitted, 1000 packets received, 77.6% packet loss
1016 packets transmitted, 1000 packets received, 1.6% packet loss
1010 packets transmitted, 1000 packets received, 1.0% packet loss
1015 packets transmitted, 1000 packets received, 1.5% packet loss
1116 packets transmitted, 1000 packets received, 10.4% packet loss
1013 packets transmitted, 1000 packets received, 1.3% packet loss
1012 packets transmitted, 1000 packets received, 1.2% packet loss
1014 packets transmitted, 1000 packets received, 1.4% packet loss
1448 packets transmitted, 1000 packets received, 30.9% packet loss
```

Resetting of the devices doesn't really help (it does in case it malfunctioned completely, which happens from time to time). AFAIK, the maximum Ethernet cable length is 100 meter, so this should be no problem. Moreover, I'd expect some signal deterioration leading to consistently lowered transmission rate or maybe a complete failure, but not this.

Any idea what may be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was water coming through the cables, which would have been easy to find out if I had had physical access to it. The water destroyed the connector, end of the story. I'm sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your set up.  I have something similar set up at home and have *zero* packet loss.  Have you checked that your hardware is at the latest firmware and drivers?